# Background Image in Google Email Markup

Tags: google-schemas

How does Google select the background image from the Reservations email markup? Does it randomly pick an image or the airline company manually set an image for each country? Ex: http://prntscr.com/6ufrni

The code block looks like this:

```
<div jsaction="__idl_action" class="oh ci pD" style="background-image: url(https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/d1XpdToqEkmyGy-PqMuMHUtuCVVJ3oAFmPnssyZOBi3ZXGGvxUlVQy9f50LEYV8MvE91nDCSIle9S0NTReIIg_Jbls696ys0KvsG=w620-h360), url(https://ssl.gstatic.com/bt/C3341AA7A1A076756462EE2E5CD71C11/1x/il_flights_conversation_r3.jpg);"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no image property for Flight reservation [markup](https://developers.google.com/schemas/reference/flight-reservation), so we cannot set any image. Google puts default image for the back ground image.

After testing the Flight Reservation schema, picture is determined by the destination of your flight. For example, when I set SFO as my destination, I see the San Francisco Bay Bridge as the default picture. When I set JFK NY as my destination, I see New York as the default picture.

Comment: Thank you @SGC, I was just wondering if there's a way to manually set a default image. Google should give this option.